# IntelliTrace - Assembly Binding Error: Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio-2015

I am having this error in vs2015 whenever i save randomly, I get an error, i have to close the solution without saving, close without saving, loose the changes, load the solution again,  and continue coding until it happens again.

Here is the fuslogvw log

> *** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (1/27/2023 @ 6:41:02 AM) ***
>
> The operation failed. Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot
> find the file specified.
>
> Assembly manager loaded from:
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll Running under
> executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
> 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\IntelliTrace\14.0.0\IntelliTrace.exe
> --- A detailed error log follows.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Web.Administration, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35  (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
> file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
> 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/IntelliTrace/14.0.0/ LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL LOG: Cache Base =
> NULL LOG: AppName = IntelliTrace.exe Calling assembly : (Unknown).
> === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
> Visual Studio
> 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\IntelliTrace\14.0.0\IntelliTrace.exe.Config
> LOG: Using host configuration file:  LOG: Using machine configuration
> file from
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
> LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful. LOG: Attempting download of new URL
> file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
> 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/IntelliTrace/14.0.0/Microsoft.Web.Administration.DLL.
> LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files
> (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
> 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/IntelliTrace/14.0.0/Microsoft.Web.Administration/Microsoft.Web.Administration.DLL.
> LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files
> (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
> 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/IntelliTrace/14.0.0/Microsoft.Web.Administration.EXE.
> LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files
> (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
> 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/IntelliTrace/14.0.0/Microsoft.Web.Administration/Microsoft.Web.Administration.EXE.
> LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.

It seems to have something to do with intelliTrace. has anyone encountered this issue?